# Building a single page webpage too parse rss in a slideshow fashion

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I am building a dashboard style information panel. One widget will be an rss feed, it's picture and text, and will show the next item in feed every 5 seconds. I've built webkitgtk into the program.

Now, I think I need to build a j-query web page to display the rss feed to my liking, but not sure where to start. Can a helpful soul point me in the direction on where to learn this skill? I have mediocre knowledge of both html and css, yet no js or j-query knowledge.

I appreciate all non-anonymous feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i think you can't make it through without some JS skills.

And the hardest part, could be parsing the Feed, and there is a jQuery plugin that takes care on that.

https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed

After you get the feed, than you should know how to populate it on your Markup.

Use jQUery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functions to add or insert html from JavaScript.